# Inquiry about Resolving "NewConnectionError WinError 10061" in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I would like to inquire about an issue with executing "Close All Browsers" in Robot Framework. When running "Close All Browsers," Robot Framework displays the error message "NewConnectionError WinError 10061," with detailed error information as follows:

```
DEBUG : Closing all browsers.
DEBUG : DELETE http://127.0.0.1:50158/session/729684d022e2dd5a3b605c08363498a2 {}
DEBUG : Resetting dropped connection: 127.0.0.1
DEBUG : Incremented Retry for (url='/session/729684d022e2dd5a3b605c08363498a2'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARN : Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000261F85F9508>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Unable to connect because the target computer is refusing the connection.')': /session/729684d022e2dd5a3b605c08363498a2
DEBUG : Starting new HTTP connection (2): 127.0.0.1:50158
DEBUG : Incremented Retry for (url='/session/729684d022e2dd5a3b605c08363498a2'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARN : Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000261F86A5D88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Unable to connect because the target computer is refusing the connection.')': /session/729684d022e2dd5a3b605c08363498a2
...
20240119 15:31:59.385 : DEBUG : Finished Request
```

I have attempted to search online for methods to check Windows settings, and currently, there are no firewall or proxy settings configured. Could you please suggest any other possible solutions?

Thank you.

I have tried the following methods:

1. Checked Windows Firewall and Proxy settings; currently, there are no relevant configurations.

2. The browser driver version is up to date and can successfully launch the browser.

3. Selenium version is v3.141.0, and Robot Framework version is 4.0.

4. The port number is not in use.

Comment: Hi, could you please share the minimal steps from your side that reproduce the issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.